# CakePHP Overide getCrumbList

Tags: cakephp

How can I go about overiding CakePHP's code without creating it manually myself? I'm attempting to customise the getCrumbList function.

The lastClass option is applying a class to the 'li' tag sucesfully, but I'd also like to remove the link/ ahref altogether for the last tag.

Function generating crumbs

```
echo $this->Html->getCrumbList(array('class' => 'breadcrumb', 'lastClass' => 'active'), 'Home');
```

Output of getCrumbList

```
<ul class="breadcrumb"><li class="first"><a href="/">Home</a></li><li><a href="/scheduler">Scheduler</a></li><li class="active"><a href="/scheduler/downloadedplaylist">Downloaded Playlists</a></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution - You dont include the URL in addCrumb. Doh!